# How to match dates with this data structure

Tags: mysql, date, metadata

I am extending a little bit the functionalities of a wp theme,

Its about booking appartments.

Bookings are stored in a table called: $wpdb->postmeta

```
SELECT meta_value,meta_key,post_id as start_date
FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE
    meta_key = 'stay_interval' AND
    post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
            post_type = 'tvr_booking' AND
            post_status IN ('publish', 'draft') 
    )
```

Wich would return something like this (I just post one row):

```
    array(8) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#348 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2013";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "4059"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#349 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"12/14/2012";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"12/19/2012";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "3897"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#350 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"12/13/2012";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"12/21/2012";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "3942"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#346 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"12/13/2012";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"12/19/2012";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "3943"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#344 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"12/21/2012";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"12/24/2012";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "3944"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#343 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"12/26/2012";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"12/31/2012";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "3945"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#292 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"12/24/2012";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"12/25/2012";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "3946"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#338 (4) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/30/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/31/2013";}"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(13) "stay_interval"
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(4) "4021"
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

So the field we're looking for its meta_value:

```
["meta_value"]=>
        string(75) "a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2013";}"
```

The thing is that I've never seen data stored in this format.

Lets say i want to know all the appartments that are not booked between:

two dates:

```
$start_date = '05/16/2013';
$end_date = '09/16/2013';
```

Is there any function in mysql that would help me out to match the dates with the meta_value's field value?

This is more or less what I would need:

```
$bookings = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
        post_type = 'tvr_booking' AND
        post_status IN ('publish', 'draft') 
        AND ID not IN (
            SELECT post_id
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE
                meta_key = 'stay_interval' AND
                somefunction(meta_value) >= '$start_date' AND
                somefunction(meta_value) <= '$end_date'
        )
" );
```

Can it be done in mysql? If not, how could I prepare the data with PHP?

Comment: also ditch those in and not in

Comment: sql can use 'between' for dates. dont code with in and not in correlated subqueries. use joins unless u want it to perform like a dog

Comment: It's not (practically) possible to query on serialised column data. Consider using a script to normalise the table first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta_value` looks like a serialized array.
Try to [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
var_dump( unserialize( $row->meta_value ) );
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so you want to find rows which are between two dates.
The problem here: We don't have normalized data MySQL could work on.

That's going to be SLOW (slowing down with increasing amount of rows) because MySQL will have to look at all rows

Now, in a first step let's try to extract the date..
MySQL unfortunately does not offer any regular expression substitution, so we have to use string functions:

**Step 1: Trying to extract the dates**

MySQL has a set of useful string functions like [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [CHAR_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) we can use here

```
SET @meta_value := 'a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2013";}';

SET @pattern := 'start_date";s:10:"';    
SELECT SUBSTRING( @meta_value, LOCATE( @pattern, @meta_value ) + CHAR_LENGTH( @pattern ), 10 ) AS `start_date`;

+------------+
| start_date |
+------------+
| 05/16/2013 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SET @pattern := 'end_date";s:10:"';    
SELECT SUBSTRING( @meta_value, LOCATE( @pattern, @meta_value ) + CHAR_LENGTH( @pattern ), 10 ) AS `end_date`;

+------------+
| end_date   |
+------------+
| 05/18/2013 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

wohoo, that's looking great already.

**Step2: Date comparison**

Now we want to compare the date, just trying the string

```
mysql> SELECT '05/16/2013' > CURRENT_DATE;
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>'
```

Dang, fails - why? because we extracted a string, MySQL compares integers, let's make a date, MySQL has a fancy function [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '05/16/2013', '%m/%d/%Y');
+----------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '05/16/2013', '%m/%d/%Y') |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2013-05-16                             |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

nice, and comparison?

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '05/16/2013', '%m/%d/%Y') > CURRENT_DATE;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '05/16/2013', '%m/%d/%Y') > CURRENT_DATE |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     0 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '05/16/2013', '%m/%d/%Y') < CURRENT_DATE;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '05/16/2013', '%m/%d/%Y') < CURRENT_DATE |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Step 3: Wrapping into functions**

Perfect.. now let's wrap all the stuff together into two functions

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getStartDate`( metaValue TEXT ) RETURNS DATE
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE startDate DATE;
    DECLARE pattern TEXT DEFAULT 'start_date";s:10:"';

    SELECT STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING( metaValue, LOCATE( pattern, metaValue ) + CHAR_LENGTH( pattern ), 10 ), '%m/%d/%Y' ) INTO startDate; 
    RETURN startDate;
END$$

CREATE FUNCTION `getEndDate`( metaValue TEXT ) RETURNS DATE
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE endDate DATE;
    DECLARE pattern TEXT DEFAULT 'end_date";s:10:"';

    SELECT STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING( metaValue, LOCATE( pattern, metaValue ) + CHAR_LENGTH( pattern ), 10 ), '%m/%d/%Y' ) INTO endDate; 
    RETURN endDate;
END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Testing:

```
mysql> SELECT getStartDate( @meta_value );
+-----------------------------+
| getStartDate( @meta_value ) |
+-----------------------------+
| 2013-05-16                  |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT getEndDate( @meta_value );
+---------------------------+
| getEndDate( @meta_value ) |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-05-18                |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT getEndDate( @meta_value ) > '2013-05-12';
+------------------------------------------+
| getEndDate( @meta_value ) > '2013-05-12' |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        1 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT getStartDate( @meta_value ) > '2013-05-12';
+--------------------------------------------+
| getStartDate( @meta_value ) > '2013-05-12' |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM wpTest WHERE getStartDate( meta_value ) >= '2013-05-16' AND getEndDate( meta_value ) <= '2013-05-18';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| meta_value                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2013";} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Works like a charm, BUT!! it's going to be slow!

**Step 4: normalizing data (suggestion)**

If you don't want to change too much in your application so the start and end dates are actually stored into separate date fields, you can use the two functions we just build and a cool MySQL feature called triggers to manage those fields silently in the background and you can just use them for your select queries.

Let's first add those two fields to your table (make sure you replace the table name)

```
ALTER TABLE `wpTest` 
     ADD `end_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' AFTER `meta_value`,
     ADD `start_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' AFTER `meta_value`;
```

Now we got the fields we want to use for querying in the future, let's fill them with our nice functions:

```
mysql> UPDATE wpTest SET start_date = getStartDate( meta_value ), end_date = getEndDate( meta_value );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Now let's care that those fields are maintained automaticaly in the future:
We need to do this BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE, so two triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `wpTest_trg_BI` BEFORE INSERT ON `wpTest` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`start_date` = `getStartDate`( NEW.`meta_value` );
    SET NEW.`end_date` = `getEndDate`( NEW.`meta_value` );
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER `wpTest_trg_BU` BEFORE UPDATE ON `wpTest` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`start_date` = `getStartDate`( NEW.`meta_value` );
    SET NEW.`end_date` = `getEndDate`( NEW.`meta_value` );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Testing the triggers:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO wpTest (meta_value) SELECT 'a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/12/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/20/2013";}';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO wpTest (meta_value) SELECT 'a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/10/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/23/2013";}';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM wpTest;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| meta_value                                                                  | start_date | end_date   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2013";} | 2013-05-16 | 2013-05-18 |
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/12/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/20/2013";} | 2013-05-12 | 2013-05-20 |
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/10/2013";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/23/2013";} | 2013-05-10 | 2013-05-23 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

perfect, insert works, now testing updates:

```
mysql> UPDATE wpTest SET meta_value = 'a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2014";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2014";}';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECTS * FROM wpTest;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECTS * FROM wpTest' at line 1
mysql> SELECT * FROM wpTest;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| meta_value                                                                  | start_date | end_date   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2014";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2014";} | 2014-05-16 | 2014-05-18 |
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2014";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2014";} | 2014-05-16 | 2014-05-18 |
| a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"05/16/2014";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"05/18/2014";} | 2014-05-16 | 2014-05-18 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Perfect, Updates work as well.. now we don't need to use the functions in the SELECT queries which need to be fast:

```
$bookings = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
        post_type = 'tvr_booking' AND
        post_status IN ('publish', 'draft') 
        AND ID not IN (
            SELECT post_id
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE
                meta_key = 'stay_interval' AND
                start_date >= '$start_date' AND
                end_date <= '$end_date'
        )
" );
```

Hope this helps :) Have fun

Comment: But is it posible in mysql? if so, any idea how?

Comment: do you have data for us or should we spend the time to create it thus slowing it down or going thru iterations ?

Comment: updated question with the whole bookins response, as you can see. They are all stored the same way

Comment: ok mate, that took a hour, check out the updated answer and make sure you read all of it ;)

Comment: I didn't get notified on the update! I'll try to digest this and let you know. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know, by the chance, that it's possible that maybe I shouldn't apply those triggers (or update the mysql schemma at all) if I'm using wordpress? Anyways your answer help me a lot to understand my issue!

Comment: If you don't want to change WP tables for the sake of updateabliity (what a word!) you could add an additional bookings table with foreign key to wp_posts.ID and the two fields start_date and end_date, then let the trigger write into this table.

Your query then would look a bit different tho.
Let me know when you need assistance doing this.